# Is there a way to create a "?" icon action button for r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if there is a way to create a "?" icon button that when clicked it shows a pop up message explaining why behind my model. Also how would I make it horizontally inline with with my numericInput widget.

```
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
    accept = c("text/csv",
               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
               ".csv")
),

helper(shiny_tag, icon = "question-circle", colour = NULL,
    type = "markdown", title = "Help", content = "Content", size= "m", 
    buttonLabel = "Okay", easyClose = TRUE, fade = FALSE)
```

The second solution I have tried was also giving me issues as well.

```
actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog"), 

server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Somewhat important message",
        "This is a somewhat important message.",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
    ))
})


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Crystal Wai! StackOverflow tends to be more about concrete programming examples and problems, not open-ended or theoretical. Please read from https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info to see what is meant by MWE and how to better frame your question. Lacking any changes, this will likely be closed (or ignored) as "needs focus". Thanks!

Comment: (It seems easy enough to use `shiny::actionButton` and `shiny::modalDialog` to do the basics there. Alignment with your other inputs is based on a UI we know nothing about ...)

Comment: @r2evans thank you! I hope I improved my question. I am slowly learning how to use this language, sorry for original vagueness.

Comment: Getting better, thank you! It still has room for improvement. For starters: (1) you mention keeping it aligned with a `numericInput` but we don't see how the UI is setup; (2) as such, having functional/complete (albeit still minimal) `ui` and `server` components is a good start. We don't need all of the reactive blocks that do not relate to the question (an unused input is still relevant, an unplotted plot is fine, etc). Thanks!

Comment: I see, I will continue to improve my posts in the future! Thank you so much for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    class = "input-group",
    tags$span(
      style = "display: inline-block",
      numericInput("a", "Some number", 0, width = "100%")
    ),
    tags$span(
      style = "vertical-align: bottom;",
      actionButton("b", "", icon = icon("question"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$b, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Somewhat important message",
      "This is a somewhat important message.",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```